# Python connect to Microsoft SQL Server with sqlalchemy for df.to_sql: target machine actively refused connection

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

### Insert pandas df into local Microsoft SQL Server database table using df.to_sql

Created connection_url for sqlalchemy engine:

```
connection_url = URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    username="",
    password="",
    host="localhost",
    port=1433,
    database="priority",
    query={
        "driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
        "authentication": "ActiveDirectoryIntegrated",
    },
)
```

Used connection_url to create engine:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_url)
```

Attempted to insert df into SQL database table 'test1' with df.to_sql:

```
df.to_sql('test1', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

#### Received error

OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.\r\n (10061) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (10061)')

#### What I've tried

1. **Opened the SQL Port 1433**

- Ran the following in the cmd (administrator mode)

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name= "SQL Port" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=1433
```

- Checked the port has been added

```
netsh firewall show state
```

Which gave the following:

> Ports currently open on all network interfaces:
> Port   Protocol  Version  Program
> 1433   TCP       Any      (null)

2. **Replaced 'localhost' with '127.0.0.1'**
3. **Replaced 'localhost' with the hostname of SQL Server**

- I found the hostname of SQL Server by executing the following SQL query

`SELECT HOST_NAME() AS HostName`

Which returned the following (changed the name for security)

> LAPTOP-NumDig

[Edit update] 4. **Updated ODBC driver to driver 17**(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).

[Edit update] 5. **Replaced "authentication": "ActiveDirectoryIntegrated" in query with "Trusted_Connection": "yes"**

### Prior connections have worked with pyodbc package

I have been able to connect to the SQL database 'priority' and created the table 'test1' using the pyodbc package in Python.

- Connect to SQL

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};' 
                      'Server=LAPTOP-NumDig;'
                      "Database=priority;"
                      'UID=;' # username
                      'PWD=;' # password
                      )
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

- Create table called 'test1' in 'priority' database

```
cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);""")
```

#### Let me know your thoughts

What I'm wanting to do is insert a df as a table in SQL. Any suggestions would be great :)

FYI - Software & package versions:

- VSCode 1.71.2
- Python 3.9.13
- Microsoft SQL Server 2019 on Windows 10 Home 10.0  (Build 22000: )
- sqlalchemy 1.4.41
- pyodbc 4.0.34

Comment: Try using `"Trusted_Connection": "yes"` instead of `"authentication": "ActiveDirectoryIntegrated"`

Comment: @GordThompson thank you for your suggestion, I triedconnection_url=mssql+pyodbc://:@localhost:1433/priority-tool?Trusted_Connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server, and unfortunately I received the same error message as before.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that uses an alternative approach that works: passing through the exact Pyodbc string to sqlalchemy (https://pydoc.dev/sqlalchemy/latest/sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc.html).

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=LAPTOP-NumDig;DATABASE=priority;UID=;PWD="

connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_url)

df.to_sql('test1', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Note, this way of inserting took a long time to upload a df into an SQL table.

[Edit update] To make the df.to_sql() run faster, include the chunksize parameter and method='multi'. (https://towardsdatascience.com/dramatically-improve-your-database-inserts-with-a-simple-upgrade-6dfa672f1424).

I used the following code to speed up the pandas df to SQL table upload:

```
df.to_sql('test1', engine, if_exists='replace', chunksize=20, method='multi')
```

Comment: "took a long time to upload a df" - `engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_url, fast_executemany=True)` should help with that.

Comment: @GordThompson thanks for the suggestion, I use the following solution (adding chunksize parameter and method='multi') to speed up the upload process: ```df.to_sql('test1', engine, if_exists='replace', chunksize=20, method='multi') ```